# Rotate option text by 180 degree

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web page to show in a kiosk. Because of some fixing problem, the display has to be fixed up-side-down. So I have included a 'transform: rotate(180deg) style at the end of the page. All is fine.
However, the options in the dropdown box of my select element are still showing straight. How to make the text in the dropdown box also to show up-side-down. The relevant portion of the code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<style type="text/css">
  option {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Select Demo</h1>
<select>
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Toyota</option>
  <option>Mercedez</option>
  <option>BMW</option>
</select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);"); 
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible with CSS. That is a system element that is widely resilient towards custom styling.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to make your own, custom select-like widget.

Comment: @connexo: Thanks for confirming that it is not doable in CSS. Now I will look for alternative solution. Probably I will invert the text itself like "ʎɹɐnuɐſ" ([link](http://www.upsidedowntext.com/).

Comment: @ceejayoz: Thanks. Please refer my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in Chrome. Notice you are using attribute `-webkit-transform`, so this will only take effect on webkit browsers. Add additional line of JS to target non-webkit browsers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.body.setAttribute( "style", "-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);"); 
  document.body.setAttribute( "style", "transform: rotate(180deg);"); 
</script>
```

As an aside I would not recommend targeting the `body` element, rather add a wrapper div inside the body, put all your content in that, then target the wrapper with your script.

As another aside, check out your `select` when it is flipped upside down, the dropdown still shows right-way up. This approach may have some issues from the start.

Comment: _the dropdown still shows right-way up_ This is exactly the problem I want to solve.

Comment: Unless you code an entirely custom dropdown you will have this issue. For a natural `<select>` element, the browser is in control of the dropdown portion of the UI, that's why the dropdown has different styling on different browsers. For this reason the `<option>`s will always show "right way up". If you make a custom dropdown out of `div` elements the rotate will be applied to the entire thing. I did a quick search, this article shows some examples of how that could work: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has put me in the right direction. I can adapt the solution given in the link to my purpose. Give this as a separate answer and I will accept it.